# Pyarrow table create column from existing columns

Tags: python-3.x, struct, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Is there a way to use `append_column` to create a column based on columns that currently exist in a pyarrow table? I want to create a `pa.struct()` field using columns that already exist. Looking for something along the lines of the following:

```
pa_table = pa.Table.from_pandas()
pa_table.append_column(
    pa.field('new_struct_col', pa.struct([
        pa.field('col1', pa.string()),
        pa.field('col2', pa.string()),
        pa.field('col3', pa.string())])
        ),
    {pa_table.column('col1'), pa_table.column('col2'), pa_table.column('col3')}) # something like this
```

In this example, `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are columns that already exist in the pyarrow table.

Thanks!